# Why: Bash syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, mailx

so the error I'm getting is syntax error near unexpected token `fi' on the second last 'fi'. Been scratching my head for a while about this. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash  

TFILE=/tmp/scripts/pdsh_demo.tmp  
if [ -f $TFILE ]; then  
   rm $TFILE  
fi  
/usr/bin/pdsh -R ssh -w host[0001-0200] 'command | grep -v "something"' >> $TFILE    

if [ ! -s $TFILE ]; then  
    exit  
fi  
if [ -f $TFILE ]; then  
    if grep -q "something" $TFILE ; then  
        grep -i "something" $TFILE | mailx -r "test.server" -s "Critical: something" -a $TFILE "test@test.com"  
    fi   
fi
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, and the code looks fine. I'd put quotes around `$TFILE` everywhere, but that only makes a difference if the filename contains spaces or metacharacters and shouldn't cause this error with the current value. Wild guess: Are you using Cygwin, and does the script have Windows line endings?

Comment: please provide a minimal set of input data that reproduces the problem

Comment: **Always** quote your filenames in bash. (e.g. `"$TFILE"`) Otherwise, if it contains a space, the part after the space can be interpreted as a separate command, etc.. and generally cause this type of error in your code. As per Wintermute, the remainder looks fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin in this case though it doesn't so it makes no difference.@OP if you have copied any of the code from somewhere make sure that there are no weird characters anywhere.

Comment: Excellent point. How do you know it doesn't make a difference here? If the filename is `"this file.txt"`, what is the result of `if grep -a something this file.txt; then grep -i something this file.txt | ....` or `>> this file.txt` It sure **does** make a difference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This part `TFILE=/tmp/scripts/pdsh_demo.tmp` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help.....I wrote the script in Notepad++ in windows and after I seen the weird characters I double checked and re wrote the script again and I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: Yes, in that case it doesn't matter `:)`

Comment: `dos2unix myScript.sh`? Good luck.

Comment: If you wrote it in notepad++ it probably has carriage returns everywhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Always quoting filenames is sound advice, but I don't think neglecting to do so can result in an `unexpected token` syntax error (it certainly can produce _other_ errors).

Answer (score 0):

you should make this:

`if grep -q "something" $TFILE ; then`

into this:

`if [ $(grep -q "something" $TFILE) ] ; then`

1. add brackets around your args
2. space before & after brackets
3. put `then` on a new line

Answer (score -3):

in

```
if grep -q "something" $TFILE ; then
```

should be

```
if [ $(grep -q "something" $TFILE) ]; then
```

Comment: Not only is the original form correct - the exit code of the `grep` command determines whether the test succeeds - your reformulation won't work at all: `grep -q`  by design doesn't output anything, so you're testing an _empty string_, which is always false. Without `-q`, the command would break, if `grep`'s output contained whitespace.

Comment: yeah tried it just to be sure and doesnt work! Thanks though!

Comment: I didn't care about -q option for quiet, sorry.